# Complex integration on NON-simple closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Compute the following integral with the help of **Cauchy's residue theorem**.
>
> $$\int_C\cot z\,dz$$where , $C:z=4e^{4i\theta}$ , $-\pi\le \theta\le\pi$

Here , singularities of are given by $\sin z=0\implies z=n\pi; n\in\mathbb Z$.

Also, $C$ is NOT a simple closed curve.
Here,

So, $\int_C\cot z \,dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=0}^n W(C,z_k)Res(f,z_k)$.where $W$ is the winding number.

> Here, $|z|=4$. So only singularities lie in $C$ are, $0,\pi , -\pi$.

**Edit:**

Now we find out the winding numbers.

$$W(C,\pi)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{\,dz}{z-\pi}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{16ie^{4i\theta}}{4e^{4i\theta}-\pi}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\left[\ln(4e^{4i\theta}-\pi\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}=0$$

> Is it correct ? I think it is wrong. My book says that $W(C,0)=2$ but I am unable to find how . Where my fallacy ?

Comment: So far this looks good.

Comment: I get $W(C,0)=4$ as well, seems that your book is wrong. $C$ makes four full rotations; $-\pi\leq\theta\leq-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is one full roation, $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq 0$ is the next one and so on.

Comment: You only have one bounded component of $\mathbb C\setminus C([-\pi,\pi])$ and the winding number is constant on every connected component; so you already know this winding number.

Comment: How what? All of the points we're looking at lie in the interior of the circle line; the interior is a (the only) connected and bounded component, thus the winding number is constant on the interior. So without calculating we get $W(C,0)=W(C,\pi)=W(C,-\pi)$.

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake? How should I tell why you get $0$ without knowing what you did?

Comment: @  Hirshy) Please see edit in question..

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the winding number $W(C,\pi)$ using the definition? The fact that it is constant on every connected component $W\subset \mathbb C\setminus C([-\pi,\pi]) $ makes it so much easier as you only have to calculate $W(C,z_0)$ for one $z_0\in W$ and then get $$W(C,z)=W(C,z_0)$ for all $z\in W.$$ But if you insist: you have a complex integral, complex logarithm is much more complex to handle (pun intended). If you want to use the definition, you'd first have to split up the integral $\int f(z) \mathrm{d}z= \int \Re(f(t))\mathrm{d}t+i\cdot\int \Im(f(t))\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: What do mean by $C([-\pi, \pi])$ ?

Comment: $C([-\pi,\pi])=\{C(t)~|~t\in[-\pi,\pi]\}=\operatorname{im}(C)$, the image of $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $$\cot(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}$$ the denominator has simple roots in $z=\pi k,k\in\mathbb Z$. Of these only $-\pi,0,\pi$ lie in the bounded component of $\mathbb C\setminus C([-\pi,\pi])$

Let $g(z)=\cos(z),f(z)=\sin(z)$, then $$\cot(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$$ and $g$ is holomorphic in $\pi k,k\in\mathbb Z$. Thus we get for the residue:
$$\operatorname{Res}(\cot,\pi k)=\frac{g(\pi k)}{f'(\pi k)}=\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\cos(\pi k)}=1.$$

Now all there is left to do is to count the number of full rotations of $C$.